# Installation of Ros and Gazebo for ARDrone

Tags: ubuntu, ros

how to install ROS and Gazebo for a drone simulator and what are the other tools needed ? Can someone suggest me good video tutorials for installation or a good documentation for the beginner level of drone simulation in ubuntu VM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is long question to answer in one single post but I'm going to try.

For ROS and Gazebo installation, no further steps are needed more than those of ROS. Just make sure to pick the right [ROS/Gazebo combo](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions) and install the **ros-distro-desktop-full**, this will install the Gazebo ROS packages along the way.

Now, for drone simulation, there's a multitude of packages supporting either  the [Hardware-in-the-loop](http://www.autonomie.net/%5C/references/model_based_design_defs_24e.html) (if you have a real drone) or [software-in-the-loop](http://www.autonomie.net/%5C/references/model_based_design_defs_24c.html) (if you don't)

here are some links to github packages that you might want to start from :

- [tum_simulator](https://github.com/dougvk/tum_simulator)
- [rotors_simulator](https://github.com/ethz-asl/rotors_simulator)
- [hector_quadrotor](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor)

along with those packages, you'll find some good tutorials on howto too.

Cheers,

Comment: can I install the above packages in oracle VM ? when I try to install gazebo2 using "sudo apt-get install gazebo2" in ubuntu VM, it throws an error E : unable to locate package gazebo2.

Comment: Indigo is using the gazebo 2.x series, start by installing it:

sudo apt-get install -y gazebo2    # getting error in this commad
Download the source code from the gazebo_ros_pkgs github repository:

cd ~/catkin_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs.git -b indigo-devel